# Upload offline data in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, data-import

I am looking for a way to quickly upload offline data into Google Analytics. This is possible using Data Import which is a feature provided by Google Analytics itself. But doing this on daily basis is a hectic task. Is there any other functionality available using which i can automatically upload data on daily basis and view the report?

Answer (score 1):

You can automate data imports by using the Management API. [Data Import is documented here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData).

To follow the examples you first need to install the [Google API client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) for the programming language of your choice. Then you create the custom data source (same as for the manual upload) and send data there via the uploadData method. Run this at a schedule (e.g. via cron) and the task stops being hectic.